# i have a problem with selecting null fk column in sql and return them to my mvc project

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have a Table"Course"

| CourseID | WeekDayID1 | WeekdayID2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 4 |
| 1 | 2 | NULL |

alse have a table  "tblSiteWeekDay" that contains week day titles
and I also have a CourseModel

```
public class CourseModel{
public int  CoursID { get; set; }
public string WeekDayTitle1 { get; set; }
public string WeekDayTitle2 { get; set; }
}
```

some courses will be hold in 2 days of a week the other courses only hold in one day of a week.

I select all the courses with below procedure

```
select 
        CourseID, 
        tsw1.WeekDayTitle as WeekDayTitle1,
        tsw2.WeekDayTitle as WeekDayTitle2
    
    from 
    Course
    inner join tblSiteWeekDay as tsw1 on Course.WeekDayID1=tsw1.SiteWeekDayID   
    inner join tblSiteWeekDay as tsw2 on Course.WeekDayID2=tsw2.SiteWeekDayID
```

when I try to show courses in my view IT only shows courses that hold in 2 days of week
others courses that hold in one day of a week wont be shown
and below code is my html view codes

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div><span>@item.WeekDayTitle1</span>
        @if (item.WeekDayTitle2!="")
        {
        <span>و @item.WeekDayTitle2 </span> 
        }
        else
        {
            <span></span>
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a poor data model, because you should have the days-of-the-week in separate *rows* for each course, rather than in separate columns.

But, if you want to use the data model you have and show all courses, then you want `left join` rather than `inner join`:

```
select c.CourseID, 
       tsw1.WeekDayTitle as WeekDayTitle1,
       tsw2.WeekDayTitle as WeekDayTitle2    
from Course c left join
     tblSiteWeekDay tsw1 on
     on c.WeekDayID1 = tsw1.SiteWeekDayID  left join 
     tblSiteWeekDay tsw2
     on c.WeekDayID2 = tsw2.SiteWeekDayID
```